# port exclude pattern from inotifywait to fswatch

Tags: regex, bash, shell, fswatch

So I have this regex exclude pattern which works excellent with `inotifywait` on Linux: `.*\.\w+\.\w{6}`

Now I want to port it to `fswatch` on macos and use with `-e` or `-Ee` flag.
What have I tried so far without any luck:

```
-e ".*\.\w+\.\w{6}"
-Ee ".*\.[[:alpha:]]+\.[[:alpha:]]{6}"
-e ".*\..+\..{6}" # not exactly, but I'm really desperate :)
```

I've also tried these patterns with various combinations of double and single quotes and with `-e` or `-eE` combinations.

Comment: I'm too having a lot of issues with `fswatch`'s regex; it's frustrating.